# How avoid the backstack entries in dialog fragment

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, back-stack, fragment-backstack

am using the viewpager in order show the frgment with dynamic data , whenn the particular time opem the dialog the exiting support fragment manger back stack entry cleared and created the new back stack entries.

When the open the dialog i don't want the destroy the backstack entry and also don't want the new back stack entry

Comment: have you tried to show dialog using childFragmentManager? every fragment have it to open fragment inside other fragments, with its own backstack that is cleared when parent is removed